# How could Trump's campaign benefit from attacking the Netanyahu government(s)?

Tags: donald-trump, israel, campaigning

[According](https://nypost.com/2023/10/12/trump-praises-iran-backed-hezbollah-as-very-smart-after-terror-group-fires-missiles-at-israeli-troops/) to the NY Post, Trump appears to be taking some pot shots at past and present Israeli governments led by Netanyahu:

> Former President Donald Trump made an extraordinary attack on the government of Israel Wednesday night, saying Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu “let us down” by not taking part in the operation that killed a top Iranian general in early 2020
>
> [...]
>
> “They [Israel] have a national defense minister or somebody saying, ‘I hope Hezbollah doesn’t attack us from the north.’ So the following morning, they attacked,” Trump said. “They might not have been doing it, but if you listen to this jerk, you would attack from the north, because he said, ‘That’s our weak spot,’” the former president went on. “Whoever heard of officials saying on television that they hope the enemy doesn’t attack in a certain area?”

I'm trying to understand how this could possibly benefit Trump's campaign. Is there some part of the electorate that's receptive to this kind of messaging and which is at least somewhat likely to vote for Trump?

Comment: This isn't the first time and won't be the last time he does stuff like this. https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/2022/12/07/electoral-logic-behind-trumps-antisemitism-00072661

Comment: @JoeW  Upvoted your comment, without bothering to read your link.  Trump being Trump is about all the "logic" that can be expected.  Probably he's remembering he didn't get properly flattered last time Bibi spoke to him.

Comment: I think it is just another example of "I would solve this problem in 24 hours" & "if only they had listened to me!  saaad!".  Clearly, he's got a fanbase that is receptive to that.  But that's delving a bit on internal motivations.

Comment: Hard to confirm but reading suggestions that those statements got made because of praise towards Biden. https://www.rawstory.com/netanyahu-trump/  "Lemire confirmed suspicions that Trump attacked Netanyahu, with whom he enjoyed a close relationship as president, because he had praised Biden and undercut his narrative blaming the current president for the Hamas massacre."